# "Unable to locate package" errors for all software

Tags: package-management, software-sources

My `apt-get` doesn't install any programs. I try to install programs with `apt-get install` but always it shows same error: `unable to locate package`.
For example I try to install the xbmc media center; here's what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xbmc    
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done    
E: Unable to locate package xbmc
```

I have updated my package list with `sudo apt-get update`.