# How do I install ckan?

Tags: installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I have some weird problem. I am trying to install a package called ckan. When I run the command sudo apt-get ckan, I have always the same answer : 'Unable to locate the package'. In fact, I notice I have the same problem with any package.

In the 'sources.list' file in the /etc/apt/ folder I have the following information. I tried to update, but the problem still remains the same

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin...]
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This thread posted on the Ubuntu Forum sounds similar to your problem, this might help you
["Unable to locate package" errors for all software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158770/unable-to-locate-package-errors-for-all-software)

When in doubt during installation, always try running...

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Btw, I don't think ckan is included among the official packages, have a look at this link for how to install ckan 
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/install-from-package.html