# cannot install any packages using terminal

Tags: networking, package-management, software-installation

Whenever I tried to install `synaptic` or other libraries like `sudo apt-get install git-core`, etc... it's showing errors.

When it starts running but stops at 22% and also with many errors.

I am not able to install anything. When I tried to install `synaptic` using

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

it says `unable to locate package synaptic`.

The internet connections are also working. `firefox` is working but I am unable to download anything through terminal.

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu. Please add to your question the error messages returned by `apt-get`. Alternatively use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com and just add the link to your pastebin.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Related: [“Unable to locate package” errors for all software](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158770/unable-to-locate-package-errors-for-all-software), [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages by apt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a stale repository and it's failing to find the right packages due to updates.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try again.

Also, please post the error messages. Those would be a huge help in troubleshooting.